# Update ObservableCollection without blinking

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

Could someone help me, how can I update ObservableCollection, which is binded to ListView ItemSource, without blinking? When I do:

```
Contacs = _contacs;
```

the whole ListView is blinking. I would like to search in ListView too, but always after replacing the old results with new one, the listview blinks.

Comment: What do you mean by update ? Do you replace entire OC, or add/remove records.

Comment: I replace entire collection.

Comment: @rbm the "double buffering" you say has absolutely nothing to do with the problem asked. The user asked for a better way to notify the UI what happens in the backstage. The double-buffer is a bitmap optimization technique, which is valid only for Winforms (not in UWP/WPF)

Comment: @MarioVernari - i see, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, that you are reassigning the whole collection. This does not take advantage of the observability and forces the ListView to reload all items. Try to remove/add the items instead so the ListView only needs to update the Items that actually changed.

In the case of searching hiding the unmatched results might be a viable solution too. To do that create a property on your Contact type (called "IsVisible" for example) and bind it to the ListViewItems Visibility Property. (You might need the build in BooleanToVisibility Converter here)

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments using a CollectionViewSource is the correct wpf way of implementing a search filter. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39612156/4189791) answer for details on how to use it.

Comment: It makes sense, when I replace collection with new data, it blinks. So I should work only with existing source and add/remove items. Your solution with searching is good.

Comment: It is a good hack but you don't need it when you have such built in functionality using CollectionViewSource and ICollectionView.

Comment: Maybe I will create sorted collection derived from ObservableCollection. Filter property for CollectionViewSource is not supported in UWP.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/pull/349) pull request for the UWPCommunityToolkit proposes what you are looking to implement.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enable filtering in your collection then there is no actual need to perform operations directly on your collection.

Use `ICollectionView` and `CollectionViewSource` for this purpose.

As you have an `ObservableCollection` so you can do something like this.

```
ICollectionView contactsView;

public ICollectionView ContactsView
{
   get { return contactsView; }
   set 
   { 
      if(contactsView != value)
      {
          contactsView = value;
      }
   }
}
```

And in the setter of the `ObservableCollection`

```
public ObservableCollection<ContactType> Contacs
{
   get { return _contacs; }
   set
   {
      if(_contacs != value)
      {
         _contacs = value;
         ContactsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(value);
         ContactsView.Filter = ContactsFilter;
      }
   }
}
```

where `ContactsFilter` is a function with following definition.

```
bool ContactsFilter(object item)
{
   var contact = item as ContactType;

   if(condition)
     return true; //show this item in ListView.

   return false; //Do not show this item in ListView
}
```

and whenever you want to filter items you can do that just by

```
ContactsView.Refresh();
```

which I think will be in the `TextChanged` Event of your text box in which you are entering search query.

More detailed article is at [CollectionViewSource](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html)

Comment: Thank you. I will try it. :)

Comment: Sure. Let me know how it goes. I recommend this because it separates your filtering logic.

Comment: I have one problem. Property Filter is not in UWP :/

Comment: I have seen and apparently this is not supported in UWP. Your question was not specific to only uwp. I answered in WPF perspective and it is supported there. I guess you will have to perform filtration on direct observable collection or you can follow this approach. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-filter-data-in-view-acbd98f2